# ios constantly displaying loading spinner for mobile web app

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, mobile, mobile-safari

I have a mobile app using angular.js, Twitter Bootstrap, and grunt with a .NET back end. that after login will constantly show the loading spinner up in the top nav next to the time and battery status.  We make server calls at login through a factory using a timeout and promise.

```
login: function (credentials) {
    var that = this;
    return login(credentials)
      .then(function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          that.getFamily().then(function (family) {
            $cookies.familyId = family.id.toString();
            Cart.getCart();
          });
        }, 100);
      });
  }

var login = function (credentials) {
  return $http.post('/family/login', credentials);
};
```

We aren't using long polling, so all of the solutions to that problem that I've found won't help.  It only happens on mobile safari on ios.  Nothing on chrome, firefox, etc. in browser or on mobile devices.  I've tried setting a datetime stamp on the POST as well as removing various apple meta tags and nothing helped.  I've read around and I've seen all over that there are issues with ios6+ caching posts, which could cause the never ending spinner.  I've also just read it's an ios bug, so who knows.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have observed the same problem for fullScreen iOS webApp's installed on the homeScreen. I'm sure it's a bug, but I can remove the spinner with a hard reSet or by reStarting the device. After reSet, the webApp runs without problems until the day the device detects some random netWork problem on loading the app. This problem is remembered by your device until it's reSat.
The bug first occured in iOS 6 but unfortunately not solved on iOS 7.